# Call external api from Web API synchronously

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I need to call an external api from my Web API 2 controller, similar to the requirement here:

[Calling external HTTP service using HttpClient from a Web API Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222998/calling-external-http-service-using-httpclient-from-a-web-api-action)

However, the solution above requires adding the `async` keyword to my api method's GET call, thus making my call asynchronous. I prefer to present clients of my API with a synchronous method but still be able to call the external api from my own (and will need that to return before my api returns). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 17):

Blocking on an `async` operation could be dangerous. It hurts performance and could lead to deadlocks (more in [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/))

But if you're sure that's what you want to do, It's better IMO to use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = httpClient.GetAsync(_endpoint).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    // Do stuff...
}
```

It's the same whether it's a `Task` or `Task<T>`, it's the same call `await` translates to (although with `await` the task already completed) and `Task.Result` (or `Task.Wait`) wraps any exceptions in `AggregateException` while `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` throws only the first `Exception` as `await` does.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up... after some further research I determined it's better to let the client decide whether to call the api asynchronously or not. I also found this article that explains the issue more concisely: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html