# calling multiple web api calls synchronously in a web api method using c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, synchronous

I Have a web api that internally makes multiple web api calls and retuns one result at the end. These multiple methods take different time to execute and as a result I'm getting timeout exception in my function.

For ex:

DeleteAccount is my web api method and it calls another web api method DeleteExistingAccount. This DeleteExistingAccount has multiple method calls say method1, method2, method3, method4. As these are executing asynchronously I'm getting Timeout error in my DeleteAccount method.

How can I achieve the method1, method2, method3, method4 to execute synchronously one after the other.

```
/////This is my web api method
public IHttpActionResult DeleteAccount([FromUri] string acctId, [FromUri] string email = "")
    {
            if (PicUpHelper.IsValidUserRequest())
            {
                string baseUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIURL"].ToString();
                string url = string.Format("/api/deleteaccount/{0}", acctId);
                var clientRequest = new RestClient(baseUrl);
                var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.DELETE);


                IRestResponse response = clientRequest.Execute(request);
                //// When I look at the response I have the timeout here
                var content = response.Content; // raw content
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    }
}

///My web api method will invoke this web api method
 public WebApiResultEx<string, string> DeleteAccount([FromUri] string acctId, [FromUri] string email = "")
    {
        WebApiResultEx<string, string> oDelAcctRes = new WebApiResultEx<string, string>();
        Account oAccountInfo = new Account();
        MyDbContext DbCtxt = new MyDbContext();

        AccountAPIController oAccountAPIController = new    AccountAPIController();
        var oAcctInfo = oPlatAccountAPIController.Get(acctId);

      if (!oAcctInfo.HasError > 0)
            {
                oAcctInfo = (Models.Api.Account)(object)oAcctInfo.Data;

                //second method
                oRes = oAccountAPIController.DeleteAcct(acctId);
            }
    return oRes;
   }
```

Thanks
Tarak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call external api from Web API synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551521/call-external-api-from-web-api-synchronously)

Comment: Can you please show the code you are using?

Comment: @gabriel I have put the code can you kindly look and tell me where I'm going wrong

Comment: Okay a few things, 1. Why call different controller actions? I would suggest abstracting the code in the controller into service classes and then call those methods rather than the controllers directly. It makes it easier to reuse the code. 2. What is the exact error message your are getting? 3. How long do the methods take to execute?

Comment: @gabriel, the DeleteAccount is a proprietory code that we included in our project, we cannot merge the controllers. However we can find the solution and suggest to the client. They will update their controller and resends back.

Comment: Okay fair enough. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: When I debug the oRes has some valid string value in it but when i F10 upto the  response.Content; in my controller I get a timeout message in the response, whereas it should the valid string returned by the web api method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107722/discussion-between-tarak-and-gabriel).